# Error Illegal return statement al emplear return

Tags: javascript, jquery

con el alerta y lo que deseo hacer es que por ejemplo si paraAcentral2  llega vacía o pextremos2  llega vacía me muestre el alaer diciendo que no es modulación estandar, pero al colocarle return false para que no se ejecute mas el codigo me aparece el error de > Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement o como hago que para apenas me muestre el aler ya se pare y no siga ejecutando mas codigo.

```
if (check.checked & minusTP == '810') {
     if (paraAcentral2 == "" || pextremos2 == "") {
          alert("No es modulación estandar.")
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1170, 500);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000";
          ctx.stroke();
          return false;   
       }  
   }
```

la idea es que el *return* no deja seguir dibujando en el *canvas*

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

Comment: puedes añadir mas información, Pon el contexto del código y quien lo llama.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no das el código del método entero me voy a limitar a interpretar el código que has pasado:
El fallo te lo da porque el `return` está dentro del `if`, y aunque tú des por hecho que vaya a entrar en el `if` el "interprete" del código no lo sabe.
Es decir, si no entras en el `if`, el código no va a devolver nada porque no hay un `return` fuera, así que el código debería ser algo así:

```
function nombreFuncion(){
    var booleano=true; //Pongo true porque doy por hecho que quieres que sea 
                       //el valor por defecto.
    if (check.checked & minusTP == '810') {
     if (paraAcentral2 == "" || pextremos2 == "") {
          alert("No es modulación estandar.")
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1170, 500);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000";
          ctx.stroke();
          booleano=false;   
       }  
   }
    return booleano;
}
```

Con este código te aseguras que si entra en el `if` te va a devolver un `false`, pero si las variables paraAcentral2  o pextremos2 no llegan vacías, retorna `true`.

Answer (score 0):

En principio debes quitar el `return false;`, ya que como veras **javascript** te indica que no va ahi, ahora que si por alguna razón que desconozco (ya que el código que das no es suficiente como para determinar el porque del error) el  `return false;` debe ir ahi, pues lo  único que se me ocurre que hagas es atrapar el error con `try {..} cat (err) {...}`.

Ejemplo:

```
    if (check.checked & minusTP == '810') {
     if (paraAcentral2 == "" || pextremos2 == "") {
      alert("No es modulación estandar.")
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1170, 500);
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000";
      ctx.stroke();
      try {
       eval("return false;");
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
     }
    }
```

Debes tener en cuenta que esta respuesta es para dar una solución basada en el contexto que das (que es prácticamente nada), quedara de tu parte optar por ella o dar mayor información para una respuesta absoluta al problema.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, la idea es que al darle aceptar al alter ya se detenga.

Comment: Probaste el código que te deje, que tal?... el programa hace lo que quieres o no?